# Powerpoint Changing Slide at Specific Time

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I was wondering if there is a script that I can add to my powerpoint presentation to allow it to change to a specific slide at a given computer time.

For example I would like the powerpoint to loop through some slides and then at 10am I would like it to go to a slide that is hidden from the loop and stay at that slide. I was wondering if that could be done? If possible that would be amazing and I would love it if it could :)

Comment: See this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/9f6891f2-d0c4-47a6-b63f-48405aae4022/powerpoint-run-macro-on-timer to create a timer for PowerPoint.  Then put code in to check the current time vs the time you want to go to the slide and then if the time has reached this time, go to that slide.

Comment: @OpiesDad I suggest that you move your comment to an answer....

Answer (score 0):

See this link: social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/… to create a timer for PowerPoint.

Then put code in to check the current time vs the time you want to go to the slide and then if the time has reached this time, go to that slide.